# How to replace double slash in bytes Python

Tags: python-3.x, string, python-2.7

I'm trying to initialize pattern for regexp as byte type. Like this:

```
pattern = b': ([A-Z][\w]+something)'
```

But when I tried to print it, I had the following output:

```
print(pattern)
output: b': ([A-Z][\\w]+something)'
```

It's not the result, that I expected to have.

I've tried to use rb identifier, but it also doesn't work.

```
pattern = rb': ([A-Z][\\w]+something)'
print(pattern)
output: b': ([A-Z][\\w]+something)'
```

Also I understand that I can replace all '\' with '\', but it doesn't fit into my case. I need a right pattern after initialize it.

I'm using python3, but I'd be happy to get an answer which works for both versions of python.

Comment: your expected output please

Comment: *"I'm trying to initialize pattern for regexp as byte type"* - Why? (i.e., why not from a regular string?)

Comment: b': ([A-Z][\\w]+something)'  it is expected output

Comment: @IvanVankovich How is that different from what you're actually getting? It looks the same to me.